# Codeigniter undefined variable when "get", but not when "get_where"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm a bit confused. I was reading a tutorial (is very clearly).
I tried to do a single line query with `$this->db->where()` method and it worked very well. But when I use a multirow with `$this->db->get()` which is inside a method, it returns "undefined variable"

**mproyecto.php** (model)

```
class Mproyecto extends CI_Model{    

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    //Codeigniter : Write Less Do More
  }

  function get($id){
    return $this->db->get_where('proyectos', array('id' => $id))->row();
  }

  function getAll(){
    $proyectos = $this->db->get('proyectos');
    return $proyectos->result();
  }
}
```

**cproyecto.php** (controller)

```
class Cproyecto extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    //Codeigniter : Write Less Do More    
  }

  function index()
  {
    $this->load->model('mProyecto','Proyecto');
    $data['proyecto'] = $this->Proyecto->getAll();    
    $this->load->view('proyecto/vproyecto', $data);
  }
}
```

**vproyecto**(view)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php foreach ($proyecto as $d){?>
    <h1><?php echo $d->$nombre; ?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo $d->$descripcion; ?></h2>
    <h3>Horas: <?php echo $d->$horas_totales; ?></h3>
    <h4>Fecha limite: <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($d->$deadline)); ?></h4>
    <?php } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

It throws:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: nombre
>
> Filename: proyecto/vproyecto.php
>
> Line Number: 9
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\teamworkplus\application\views\proyecto\vproyecto.php
>   Line: 9 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\teamworkplus\application\controllers\cproyecto.php
>   Line: 18 Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\teamworkplus\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\teamworkplus\application\views\proyecto\vproyecto.php
>   on line 9 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Cannot access empty property
>
> Filename: proyecto/vproyecto.php
>
> Line Number: 9
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: make it like this `$d->nombre`. Remove `$`.

Comment: @UnsignedFoo if possible then please edit the question title because it's nothing  to do with `get`or  `get_where`

Answer (score 4):

Remove `$` symbol from property name

```
 <?php foreach ($proyecto as $d){?>
    <h1><?php echo $d->nombre; ?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo $d->descripcion; ?></h2>
    <h3>Horas: <?php echo $d->horas_totales; ?></h3>
    <h4>Fecha limite: <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($d->deadline)); ?>
   </h4>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: wow! That did the trick! Thank you! I felt little bit embarrassed

Comment: @JYoThi - a little mistake in <?php echo $d-$horas_totales; ?> $d-$ should be $d-> :)

Answer (score 0):

you can write your `view` code to this way

```
<?php foreach ($proyecto as $d){?>
    <h1><?php echo $d->nombre; ?></h1>
    <h2><?php echo $d->descripcion; ?></h2>
    <h3>Horas: <?php echo $d->horas_totales; ?></h3>
    <h4>Fecha limite: <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($d->deadline)); ?></h4>
    <?php } ?>
```

`$d->$nombre` its wrong `nombre` not used with `$` sign

so change in all the variable with `$` symbol